# TFS automatically checks out a windows form when the form is opened in VS2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a VS2010 Winforms project with several forms and user controls, all integrated with TFS.  Every time I open one of the forms in the designer, it checks itself out and acts like changes have been made, even though none have.  This happens for everyone working with this project, and only happens with this one particular form.  Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the WinForms designer regenerates the form.designer.cs file whenever you open it, thus causing a checkout.  Of course the file doesn't end up with any different code, but it got rewritten again.

Also, if you have code in your constructor, this DOES get run by the designer.  Maybe that code is is setting a property on a control (but not to a new value) which causes the designer to want to regenerate the file.

Comment: The good news is that when you check the files in, TFS will do a compare, and if the contents are the same, it will silently undo the checkout, essentially saying "never mind".

Comment: So why does it happen on this form and not any of the others?  @Mel, yes, that is a good thing, but it's still an annoyance that it checks it out to begin with.

Comment: If you do allow the file to be checked-in, does it appear in the history/changeset as a change to that file, or does it ignore it as Mel describes? I'm just wondering if it's a very minor change e.g. my encoding suggestion below, or perhaps a small amount of whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be changing the encoding? Locate the file in the Pending Changes window and see if the Change is listed as "type,edit".

Comment: It is listed as simply "edit."  If I check in that form in the Solution Explorer, I end up getting a message: "No changes to check in.  All of the changes were either unmodified files or locks.  The changes have been undone by the server," as Mel suggested.

Comment: The history does not list the change, either.